# Cannot build capybara-webkit 1.3 on Windows 7 64-bit (ruby 2.1.3)

Tags: windows, qt, capybara-webkit

I've followed the process outlined in [the guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit) for several different versions of Qt (I've tried 4.8.4, 4.8.5 and 4.8.6 - now trying 4.5.4), but none have managed to complete the `rake build step`.

This is my current environment:

```
which qmake 
C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\bin\qmake.EXE

which ruby 
C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\ruby.EXE

which make 
C:\Ruby21-x64\devkit\bin\make.EXE
```

And this is the current error returned from running `bundle exec rake build` in the capybara-webkit repository.

```
H:\capybara-webkit>bundle exec rake build
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
c:/Qt/5.4/msvc2013_64/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ CONFIG\+\=test -o Makefile w
ebkit_server.pro
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile.webkit_server || c:/Qt/5.4/msvc2013_64/bin/qmake.e
xe H:/capybara-webkit/src/webkit_server.pro -spec win32-g++ CONFIG\+\=test -o Ma
kefile.webkit_server ) && make -f Makefile.webkit_server
make[1]: Entering directory `/h/capybara-webkit/src'
c:/Qt/5.4/msvc2013_64/bin/qmake.exe -spec win32-g++ CONFIG+=test -o Makefile.web
kit_server webkit_server.pro
make[1]: Leaving directory `/h/capybara-webkit/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/h/capybara-webkit/src'
make -f Makefile.webkit_server.Release
make[2]: Entering directory `/h/capybara-webkit/src'
g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o release/webkit_server.exe object_
script.webkit_server.Release  -LC:/Qt/5.4/msvc2013_64/lib -lQt5WebKitWidgets -lQ
t5Widgets -lQt5WebKit -lQt5Gui -lQt5Network -lQt5Core
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined refere
nce to `__imp__ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_yy'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined refere
nce to `__imp__ZN9QListData7disposeEPNS_4DataE'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x167): undefined refer
ence to `__imp__ZN9QListData11shared_nullE'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x16e): undefined refer
ence to `__imp__ZN7QString16fromAscii_helperEPKci'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x289): undefined refer
ence to `__imp__ZeqRK7QStringS1_'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x2fa): undefined refer
ence to `__imp__ZN7QString6appendERKS_'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x4b7): undefined refer
ence to `__imp__ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_yy'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x4e5): undefined refer
ence to `__imp__ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_yy'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x515): undefined refer
ence to `__imp__ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_yy'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x595): undefined refer
ence to `__imp__ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_yy'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x5c0): undefined refer
ence to `__imp__ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_yy'
./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o:SetUnknownUrlMode.cpp:(.text+0x5e6): more undefined
references to `__imp__ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_yy' follow
c:/ruby21-x64/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x
86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./build/SetUnknownUrlMode.o: bad reloc address 0x0
 in section `.pdata'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [release/webkit_server.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/h/capybara-webkit/src'
make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/h/capybara-webkit/src'
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
Command 'make' failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has problems compiling capybara-webkit on Windows (and doesn't want to spend two days in google-purgatory) they can [read this](http://nhh.co/blog/2015/01/28/getting-capybara-webkit-working-on-windows/).

Comment: Don't forget to look at the comments there. It seems like there some extra steps to take. All in all that's the full solution.

Comment: Are there any instruction on installing webit using Qt5 or higher on windows? So far I've only seen Qt 4.8.5